# how to populate values to list box from a string array

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a string array and  i need to populate its value to a list box.but the values are not get in the list box. here is my code

## xaml

```
    '<ListBox Name="listBox_1"  Background="White" Margin="3,131,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC1BCBC" Width="480">
                        <Grid Height="80">
                            <TextBlock Name="list" 
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Names}"
                                       FontSize="36"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>'
```

## class

```
        'public class Names
{
    //Model Class to hold Category details

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string[] Names { get; set; }
    public string[] Value { get; set; }
}'
```

## xaml.cs

```
        'protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

      string[] name = ((Application.Current as App).obj_category.Names);
          listBox_1.ItemsSource=name;



    }'
```

i didnt get the names displayed in the list box.but i got the border lines that is, if the string contain 3 names i got three blank rows.why the text in it doesnot display?could any one help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContext` in your `ListBox` is of type `string[]` and `DataContext` in each `DataTemplate` is a `string` which doesn't have a property `Name`.

Change `Text="{Binding Path=Name}"` to `Text="{Binding}"`.